# Enable growth of VirtualBox guest's disk

Tags: virtualbox

I am running VirtualBox (version 5.0.24) with a `Windows 10` guest under `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`. In the storage settings, the "Virtual Size" is stated to be `32 GB` and the "Actual Size" is `30.2 GB`. Dynamically allocated storage is used. In addition (not sure if this is relevant), `LVM` is used in `Ubuntu`.

I am trying to install software that will take an additional `4 GB` in my Windows guest and get the "Not enough space" error. What steps should I take to enable this installation? (I still have lots of free disk space in my home directory in Ubuntu, but how do I get the Windows guest to use it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the virtual disk container by using the `vboxmanage modifymedium` *(Virtualbox 5.1)* command in a terminal window. Then in the Windows guest, using Windows own `Disk Management` application to extend the size of the Windows partition.

```
$ vboxmanage (by itself to see the long help info)

  modifymedium              [disk|dvd|floppy] <uuid|filename>
                            [--type normal|writethrough|immutable|shareable|
                                    readonly|multiattach]
                            [--autoreset on|off]
                            [--property <name=[value]>]
                            [--compact]
                            [--resize <megabytes>|--resizebyte <bytes>]
                            [--move <full path to a new location>]
```

So to resize your 30G disk container to 45G, you'd do:

```
sudo vboxmanage modifymedium disk disk_container_name.vdi --resize=45000
```

**note**: In Virtualbox versions prior to 5.1, the `modifymedium` option may have been called something else. The command works the same, however. Type `vboxmanage` to get the help info for your specific version.

Comment: What is the safest way to do this in Windows 10 guest?

Comment: I used this and it worked: https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Windows own **Disk Management** program would be the first choice. Cheers, Al